# What's the condition that i can use to print out all the strings that meet the conditions

Tags: c++

I want to print out all the books that have "childrensbook" type at the end

for example :

```
bookname : tower
booktype : drama
bookname : flower
booktype : childrensbook
bookname : sun
booktype : childrensbook
...
...
...
```

The children books are :

- flower
- sun

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string.h>
  using namespace std;

  class Books
  {
     public:
        string name;
        string type;
    
    
    void getdetails() {
        cout <<"enter book's name :  ";
        cin >> name;
        cout <<"enter book's type :  ";
        cin >> type;
        cout << endl;
        }
    
    };



   int main() {

    string name2[19];
    string type2[19];
    string test = "childrensbook";
    Books book1;

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) 
    {
        cout << "Book " << (i+1) << " info : " << endl;
        book1.getdetails();
        name2[i] == book1.name;
        type2[i] == book1.type;
    
        if(test == book1.type)
        {
            /*HERE I WANT TO SAVE THE BOOKS THAT ACTUALLY HAVE 
            "childrensbook" TYPE AND PRINT THEM OUT */
        
        }
    
    }   
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Is this current code not working?

Comment: What's the include of `string.h` for. If you want to include the C header, use `#include <cstring>`, but probably the appropriate include here would be `#include <string>`... Also why are there 2 arrays of strings instead of one array of `Books`? Why is the name of the class describing a single book plural?

Comment: the code is working but how am i gonna print out all the strings that meet the conditions

Comment: `cout << book1.name << endl;` instead of the comments will do. You are already looping through all the input books, and the condition is OK.

Comment: Your `name2` and `type2` variables are useless and should be removed.

Comment: what do you mean by saving the book?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
public:
    string name;
    string type;

    void getdetails() {
        cout << "enter book's name : ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "enter book's type : ";
        getline(cin, type);
    }
};

int main() {

    string test = "childrensbook";
    Book books[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Book " << (i+1) << " info : " << endl;
        books[i].getdetails();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (books[i].type == test)
        {
            cout << "bookname : " << books[i].name << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/gsUoTz)